# How to generating key pair from private key using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

How can I generate key pairs from private key stored as string? First I generate random key pairs like here:

```
ECNamedCurveParameterSpec curve = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
ECDomainParameters domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(curve.getCurve(), curve.getG(), curve.getN(), curve.getH(), curve.getSeed());

SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
ECKeyGenerationParameters keyParams = new ECKeyGenerationParameters(domainParams, secureRandom);

ECKeyPairGenerator generator = new ECKeyPairGenerator();//("ECDSA");
generator.init(keyParams);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();

ECPrivateKeyParameters privkey = (ECPrivateKeyParameters) keyPair.getPrivate();
String privateKey = privkey.getD().toString();
ECPublicKeyParameters pubkey = (ECPublicKeyParameters) keyPair.getPublic();
String publicKey = pubkey.getQ().toString();
```

Now I have `privateKey`. How can I now generate `AsymetricCipherKeyPair` using that private key?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You already have the key pair, at `generator.generateKeyPair()`. It is that which you should be transforming, or typecasting, or whatever is required. Not the private key. If public and private keys could be derived from each other the whole of PKI would be utterly pointless.

Answer (score 4):

[`AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/AsymmetricCipherKeyPair.html#AsymmetricCipherKeyPair-org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter-org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter-) has a constructor that expects a public key in the first parameter and a private key in the second parameter, both of type [`AsymmetricKeyParameter`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/AsymmetricKeyParameter.html), the common base class of [`ECPrivateKeyParameters`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/ECPrivateKeyParameters.html) and [`ECPublicKeyParameters`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/ECPublicKeyParameters.html).

One way to derive an `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` instance from an `ECPrivateKeyParameters` would be to first derive an `ECPublicKeyParameters` instance and then use the above constructor, e.g.:

```
// Your code
...
ECPrivateKeyParameters privkey = (ECPrivateKeyParameters) keyPair.getPrivate();
...

// Create AsymmetricCipherKeyPair from ECPrivateKeyParameters 
BigInteger d = privkey.getD();
ECPoint q = privkey.getParameters().getG().multiply(d);
ECPublicKeyParameters pubkeyRecreated = new ECPublicKeyParameters(q, privkey.getParameters());      
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPairRecreated = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(pubkeyRecreated, privkey);
```

Note that *technically* an `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` instance can also be created with the private key only, i.e. if `null` is passed for the public key. In this case, however, `AsymmetricKeyParameter#getPublic()` returns `null` unlike the code above. Similarly, an `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` instance can also be created with the public key only.

For completeness: While deriving the public key from the private key is possible, the reverse is of course not possible, since otherwise, as already indicated in the comment, the entire public key cryptography would be pointless.